# SBT cross building - choosing a different library version for different scala version

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to configure SBT to use a completely different library version when cross building, depending on the scala version the project is being built with?

For example:

- When building with Scala `2.9.2` I want to use `"org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.9.2" % "2.0.M5" % "test"`
- When building with scala `2.10.0` I want to use `"org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10.0-RC5" % "2.0.M5-B1" % "test"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion(scalatestDependency(_))

def scalatestDependency(scalaVersion: String) = scalaVersion match {
  case "2.9.2" => "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.9.2" % "2.0.M5" % "test"
  case "2.10.0" => "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10.0-RC5" % "2.0.M5-B1" % "test"
}
```

I assumed that you actually meant that the library versions should be the other way around? :-)

You can see variations on this theme in the [ScalaMock 2 build](https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/blob/ScalaMock2/project/Build.scala).

Comment: Thanks! It works. My Scala version was coming through as `2.10.0-RC5` so I had to change the match statement to use a regex as shown in the link. It would be great if there was a way to do this purely in a .sbt file, but I am assuming there isn't at the moment?

Comment: @kim - many thanks for fixing my stupid error in the code (blush).

Comment: @theon - I'm not aware of any way to do this in an .sbt file I'm afraid.

Comment: Well, just merge the two things together, if you want to do that in the `.sbt` file: `libraryDependencies <+= scalaVersion { case "2.9.2" => ... }`