# How to specify different libraryDependencies per sbtVersion in sbtPlugin with sbt-cross-building and sbt 0.13?

Tags: scala, sbt

I use [Sbt Cross Building Plugin](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-cross-building) with sbt `0.13.1`. It works fine, but I had to specify the lower common dependency versions for all the `CrossBuilding.crossSbtVersions` defined.

How can I define `libraryDependencies` so it uses the most recent dependency version per `sbtVersion in sbtPlugin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following solution for `CrossBuilding.crossSbtVersions := Seq("0.12", "0.13")` in `build.sbt` works well:

```
libraryDependencies <++= (sbtVersion in sbtPlugin) { version =>
  val V013 = """0\.13(?:\..*|)""".r
  val (scalaz, scalatest) = version match {
    case V013() => ("7.1.0-M4", "2.0.1-SNAP3")
    case _ => ("7.0.5", "2.0.M6-SNAP3")
  }
  Seq(
    "org.scalaz"    %% "scalaz-concurrent" % scalaz    % "embedded",
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest"         % scalatest % "test")
}
```

Inspired by [SBT cross building - choosing a different library version for different scala version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13982853/1305344).

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
libraryDependencies <++= (sbtVersion in sbtPlugin) { version =>
  val (scalaz, scalatest) = version match
    case v if v startsWith "0.12" => ("7.0.5", "2.0.M6-SNAP3")
    case v if v startsWith "0.13" => ("7.1.0-M4", "2.0.1-SNAP3")
  }

  Seq(
    "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-concurrent" % scalaz % "embedded",
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalatest % "test")
}
```

It will pick things like "0.121" incorrectly. You could have a regex matcher for that:

```
val V012 = """0\.12(?:\..*|)""".r
val V013 = """0\.13(?:\..*|)""".r
```

And then use `case V012() => ...`, etc.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks! How could I merge our answers to make one better than ours being separate and at the same time award yours? Please advice.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Don't mind me. Edit your answer to fit what you expect and select it.

Comment: I found [a solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5240) - I'll create a single `community wiki` answer and accept it with yours marked as useful. Deal?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I really don't mind it. :) You did all the work on your answer, I just offered a way to reduce repetition.