# How to make sbt compile different sources for different library versions?

Tags: scala, sbt, cross-build

I understand that cross-building across different Scala versions is easy with SBT. You just put your files which fail to compile in `scala-2.10` and `scala-2.11` directories instead of `scala`. However, If I want to cross build for different versions of Scala **and** for different versions of a dependency (say, Spark 1.6 and 2.1) then how can that be done?

Comment: Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982853/sbt-cross-building-choosing-a-different-library-version-for-different-scala-ve?rq=1

Comment: I did. But it just talks about using different versions of libraries for different versions of Scala. I want to build both the versions of Scala with both the versions of Spark.

Comment: Oh, I see. So you want four different output artefacts. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You can't use two versions of a direct dependency (here Spark) in the same project. So you should have two different projects or two Git branches, one with each version of Spark.