# SBT[1.1.1] Different libraryDependencies for different Scala Versions

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I have tried the solution from: [SBT cross building - choosing a different library version for different scala version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982853/sbt-cross-building-choosing-a-different-library-version-for-different-scala-ve) however this results in

```
build.sbt:27: error: No implicit for Append.Value[Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID], sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID]] found,
  so sbt.Def.Initialize[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID] cannot be appended to Seq[sbt.librarymanagement.ModuleID]
    libraryDependencies += scalaVersion(jsonDependency(_)),
                    ^
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
```

What is the correct way of forcing library dependencies for different Scala versions in sbt 1.1.1?

#### build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += scalaVersion(jsonDependency(_))

def jsonDependency(scalaVersion: String) = scalaVersion match {
  case "2.11.7" => "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.4.2"
  case "2.12.4" => "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.9"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line should be:

```
libraryDependencies += jsonDependency(scalaVersion.value)
```

As for the rest, it's unnecessarily sensitive to exact Scala version numbers. Consider using `CrossVersion.partialVersion` to be sensitive to the Scala major version only, as follows:

```
def jsonDependency(scalaVersion: String) =
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" %
    (CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion) match {
      case Some((2, 11)) => "2.4.2"
      case _             => "2.6.9"
    })
```