# Cross-compiling a plugin for Spark against different versions of Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, cross-compiling

#### Description

I am currently a maintainer of a plugin for Apache Spark. In our environment, we have several versions of Spark deployed (2.2.x, 2.3.x, 2.4.x) and the maintainers of the said environment want to introduce Spark 3.1.x into the environment.

A problem arose when they attempted to test Spark 3.1.x, because of the binary incompatibility of Scala between "major" Scala versions.

For reference in our environment, Spark 2.2.x, 2.3.x and 2.4.x are compiled using Scala 2.11; Spark 3.1.x, on the other hand, is compiled using Scala 2.12.

Enter the binary incompatibility "feature". I've read the `sbt` documentation on cross-compiling, however the documentation only ever focuses on a 1-dimensional problem, i.e., compiling the same code against different versions of Scala, whereas my problem appears to be more nuanced, i.e., compiling the same code against different versions of Spark AND Scala, based on the version of Spark being referenced.

#### Goals

1. Keep the source code the same
2. Use `sbt` to cross-compile the plugin against the various Spark versions AND Scala versions, based on the condition that if it's Spark 2.2.x - 2.4.x use Scala 2.11, whilst if it's Spark 3.1.x we're dealing with then use Scala 2.12.

For reference:

This [question seems to be on the right path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982853/sbt-cross-building-choosing-a-different-library-version-for-different-scala-ve), however I'm not able to translate it to my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend having a look to sbt-projectmatrix which can help you build for multiple "axes" like Scala version + something else.

Comment: But it might not even be necessary if each version of Spark for instance is associated to a single Scala version. Depends on your need :)

Comment: @marley Did you happen to find a resolution to this problem or any alternate ways you tackled it?